# android listfragment created twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is code where my fragment is created:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            FlightListFragment listFragment = 
                     FlightListFragment.newInstance(mSearchParams);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
                    android.R.id.content, listFragment).commit();
 }
```

But all fragment methods called twice! OnCreateView, OnActivityCreated, OnStart.

Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your fragment set to retain instance? it might be possible that you're spawning 2 instances of the fragment

Maybe try adding a call to check something like

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myFragment") != null)
{
        FlightListFragment listFragment = 
                 FlightListFragment.newInstance(mSearchParams);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
                android.R.id.content, listFragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: @Chris-tulip: can you please let us know why we need to put above condition to prevent two times calling the OnCreateView, OnActivityCreated, OnStart. i was also facing the same problem and your above condition worked for me But i want to know the reason for it. thanks :)

Comment: if the fragment is set to retain instance it isn't destroyed on rotate  so you need to make sure that you don't spawn a duplicate fragment. If a duplicate fragment is spawned it would call onCreate twice :)